# What is the mininum perpendicular distance between lines formed from intersection pairs of a function and its inverse

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, inverse-function

> $f\left(x\right)=k\left(x-1\right)^3-1, \ k<0$
> $f=f^{-1} \ \text{has pairs of intersections} \ \left(x,y\right), \ \left(y,x\right), \ x\ne y$
> $\text{Lines in form of} \  y=-x+c \ \text{can be formed with a pair of such points}$
> $\text{Find} \ k \ \text{that gives maximum perpendicular distance of such lines}$

In other words, I want to find when this is length max

[image: click here for image]

Comment: I am not answering directly the question, but instead I am giving additional information to focus better the search. Let us determine the $k_{min}$ for which we have intersections. As

$$
\cases{
f(x) = k(x-1)^3-1, \ \ \ k < 0\\
f^{-1}(x) = 1 + \frac{(k^2(x+1))^{\frac 13}}{k},\ \ \ k <0
}
$$

their tangency is determined by solving for $(x, k)$

$$
\cases{
f(x)+f^{-1}(x) =0\\
f'(x)+(f^{-1})'(x) = 0
}
$$

thus obtaining

$$
k_{min}= -\frac{8}{27}
$$

so the intersections occur in the range $k\in [k_{min},0)$